# Are there examples of "liberated" Borg who, even after a long time away from the collective, wished to return?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

There are several instances that I know of Borg who ended up free from the collective.

- Picard. Did not wish to return, which is understandable considering the brief time he was Borg.
- Seven. She did express a strong desire to at first, but then decided against it.
- Third of Five also known as Hugh. He did rejoin the collective, only to be kicked out and end up with Lore. We see in Picard that

  > Hugh is still an individual, with less implants, working on helping the ex Borg on board the artifact. Not a member of the collective.

So my question is are there any known ex-Borg who wished to rejoin the collective even after long term separation? If the answer is a boldfaced no, why not? Even Picard called the experience "comforting."

Comment: Arguably all the Borg in Descent. Not posting as an answer because you already mentioned "Hugh", but he spoke for them and said they were all lost and confused without the Collective.

Comment: @Z.Cochrane - *A* collective, not *The* Collective

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Voyager episode "[Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(Star_Trek:_Voyager))". They discover that some of the disconnected Borg (an accident separated them from the Collective) *want* to go back to a hive mind (in their case, called the Co-operative).

While it's not the Collective, and they act in a way that helps *Voyager*, as Chakotay points out they still incorporated former Borg drones without consent for their "own good", and as such aren't very different from the Borg proper. The ones who initiate the Co-operative explicitly state how they liked being part of a greater whole.

Comment: I thought the Cooperative was driven to that solution by the onslaught of ex-drone raiders who rekindled old biases and rivalries (against the races and people that made up the cooperative). i.e. it wasn't that they 'wanted' to go back to a full collective, but saw no other option for their continued existence. (Doesn't excuse what they did but I understand the desperation)